# Resolve schema names in Idea Ultimate Database

Tags: sql-server, database, intellij-idea

[Intellij Idea Ultimate has Database and SQL module.](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/database_tools.html)

Very handy, but I'm having some trouble using it. I have an SQL Server I connected to with multiple databases inside it. I've configured a data source for each and selected only the the dbo schema(where the non-admin data tables lives in SQL Server as I understand it) under Schemas & Tables in the configuration. I also check "Resolve unqualified references" on that schema's `dbo`, and deselected the `master.*`

For example I selected `qa_client_1.dbo` for one of our qa testing server's schema.

Now while I can query the chosen database, I have to fully qualify the schema.

`SELECT * FROM person_info;` will return just the columns with no data rows.

`SELECT * FROM qa_client_1.dbo.person_info;` will return the columns and the data rows.

I'd like to be able to do this without fully qualifying the schema on the table.

In the past I've used [Squirrel SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) which doesn't require it but it's buggy in Linux (my dev platform) and prone to hanging when I open drop down menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out. Squirrel SQL cheats and the  cheat spoiled me.

IDEA connects to the database but you still have to tell it what schema with the 'USE schema_name;' even if you only have one schema loaded on that particular data source. It's much closer to a pure database console than Squirrel.